# How to display course list in moodle form?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to display course list in moodle form and using following code;

```
$options = array();
$allcourses = coursecat::get(0)->get_courses(array('recursive' = true);
foreach ($allcourses as $course) {
    $options[$course->id] = $course-fullname;
}
$mform->addElement('select', 'courseid', get_string('course'), $options);
$mform->setDefault('courseid', $currentcourseid);
$mform->setType(PARAM_INT);
```

But it displays error at `$allcourses = coursecat::get(0)->get_courses(array('recursive' = true);` any guidance or help?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the error message that you are getting say?

Because it looks like you have unbalanced parentheses:

```
$allcourses = coursecat::get(0)->get_courses(array('recursive' = true);
```

Try this:

```
$allcourses = coursecat::get(0)->get_courses(array('recursive' = true));
```

When in doubt, always make sure your error messages are shown:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Or, in your specific case, you might want to amend the Moodle `$CFG` object in `config.php`:

https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Debugging

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If not, then you need to change your development environment to display the errors as per my answer - otherwise you are working blind. If you are receiving an error message, please edit your answer to include it; otherwise, nobody will be able to provide a specific answer.

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
array('recursive' => true));
```

instead of (`=` instead of `=>`)

```
array('recursive' = true));
```